# jquery.event.drag - Run script for every X pixels dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am using [jquery.event.drag.js](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag) in a project I am creating, and I am trying to figure out a way to run a script for every X amount of pixels I have dragged. I am using only the X axis for this. Here is some code I have right now.

```
$('body').drag(function( ev, dd ){
    var newcell = currentCell;
    var dragOffset = Math.floor(dd.offsetX / 100);
    if (dragOffset >= 1) {
        alert("Dragged 100px");
    }
    newcell += dragOffset;
    $('#info').html(dragOffset + " | " + dd.offsetX);
    updateStack(newcell, magnifyMode);
});
```

This works, however, since this script runs for every pixel dragged, this runs the alert after 100px dragged, but from then on it runs for every pixel I drag it after that. I'm looking for a way to only run it for every 100px I drag it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have an outside variable tracking when you last did the alert:

```
var chunkedOffset = 0;
$('body').drag(function( ev, dd ){
    var newcell = currentCell;
    var dragOffset = dd.offsetX / 100;
    if (dragOffset > chunkedOffset) {
        chunkedOffset = dragOffset;
        alert("Dragged 100px");
    }
    newcell += dragOffset;
    $('#info').html(dragOffset + " | " + dd.offsetX);
    updateStack(newcell, magnifyMode);
});
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Had to make a minor edit, which was line 5 was changed to "var dragOffset = Math.floor(dd.offsetX / 100);"

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing so thought I'd try and get your code working first. However, you don't explain where 'currentCell' is defined. Could you please help me understand where this value is coming from?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely familiar with drag.js, but, you could just use modulus division to make sure its every 100px.

x % 100 - will be 0 if divisible by 100, so

```
if(dd.offsetX % 100 == 0)
{
    alert("Dragged 100px");
}
```

Comment: this only works if he gets an event for every single pixel dragged and that's unlikely to be the case when the user drags quickly

Comment: I did use that, but if you drag too fast and it registers dd.offsetX = 198 and then dd.offsetX = 201, it will miss that action.